# GarageBand sound holding/freezing when multiple notes are played on USB keyboard

Tags: garageband

I just bought a [MIDI to USB cable](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxbnw1p3EDT_tKdob7TGnQN9I42qx1N8piH4XclqXYMqR4zUwca0qIRpf4dzNkNhNubCv2kn0&usqp=CAE) so I could connect my electronic [piano/keyboard](http://www.piano-keyboard-guide.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/digital-piano.jpg) to my mac mini. I open GarageBand and the keyboard will play one note at a time just fine, but if I play two or more notes at once, then the sound will kind of spaz out, with the two or three notes just lasting forever and no sound from any new notes being played. The sound only stops if I hit the spacebar about two or three times (to press play and stop).

The keyboard and mac mini I'm using never did this with the last MIDI to USB cable I had been using previously, I only stopped using that one because it was borrowed and I had to return it. The new looks pretty much the same as the old one though, are MIDI to USB cables not all created equal or something? How can I get GarageBand to play/record what I play even when I press more than one note?

Comment: Try to use a different software. PreSonus works for me... and usually, MIDI devices work better when connected to an external device like a StudioOne. I don't know why you GarageBand isn't working, but I recommend re-starting both devices, and reconfiguring the MIDI setup.

Comment: Maybe even a less-expensive MIDI Synth

Comment: Oh... and It could be your cabe too.

Comment: What did you buy? I have the same one as you and same problem.

Comment: @MichelleBergin I got a Roland um-one midi chord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Buy a new midi cord.

I'm not sure why the first one didn't work, but I eventually bought a new midi cord/cable(s) and now the above problem doesn't happen.